# how to get values of parameters inside Controller from a dynamically created form in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have generated a dynamic form reading an xml.So the elements inside the form are dynamic.How can i get each parameters inside Controller and save it in to a database table?
Here with respect to the xml i have designed a database table to store the data. But how can i identify which dynamic parameters to be saved in corresponding fields in the table?

Comment: if you generated data that doesn't map a database table you are staying in front of firewall that prevents you to save this data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this into Controller

```
Collections.list((Enumeration<String>) request.getParameterNames());
```

In this way you should have a list of all parameters name. 
In a FOR LOOP take the values in this way :

```
request.getParameter(parametername);
```